# Maven сломался. Что делать?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Пишу CRUD приложение. Проблема в том, что при любом изменении кода (даже на jsp странице) приходится тыкать clean install перед каждым запуском сервера(Том 9.0), чтобы появились изменения. На старом компе мне достаточно было запустить сервер, а все изменения автоматически применялись. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Интереснее, как это работало на старом компе. Единственный, известный мне, способ этого добиться - [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

Comment: Возможно ли что на старом компе сервер был интегрирован с IDE и именно IDE при сохранении компилировала, собирала и запускала приложение на сервере?